# How to draw a parallelogram with characters in python?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

```
def parallelogram(a,b):
    for i in range(a,0,-1):
        for j in range (i,0,-1):
            print("*",end='')
            for j in range(b,0,-1):
                print("+",end='')
            for k in range(a-i,0,-1):
                print("*",end='')
```

ı want to write a function which can draw a parallelogram with characters in python.ı couldnt.how can i fix my code?
output must looks like this:

```
****++++*
***++++**
**++++***
*++++****
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with. If you have code, what about it doesn't do what you want? Do you get bad output? Errors? You need to actually explain what you're asking.

Comment: ı want a code give me  that output.my code  is not correct. ı couldnt find how can i fix loops to get this output

Comment: this code give me only line like this******+++++*****+++++*****+++++*****+++++*****+++++*****+++++*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASCII art you better first analyze the problem. If we want to draw a parallellogram with height `a` and width `w`, we first need to think how the first, second, *i*-th line, etc will look like.

The first line of the prallellogram will contain `a` asterisks (`*`), followed by `b` plusses (`+`) followed by one asterisk (`*`). We can write this as:

```
line1 = '*' * a + '+' * b + '*'
```

This of course does not solves the entire problem. The second line is almost equal to the first one, except that there is one asterisk less on the left side, and one more on the right side. So:

```
line2 = '*' * (a-1) + '+' * b + '*' * 2
```

Every line will remove one asterisk on the left, and add one on the right. So that means that `linei` has:

```
linei = '*' * (a+1-i) + '+' * b + '*' * i
```

Since the parallellogram has `a` such lines, we can range `i` from `1` to `a+1`:

```
for i in range(1, a+1):
    linei = '*' * (a+1-i) + '+' * b + '*' * i
    print(linei)
```

We can simplify this a bit, and write it as:

```
def parallelogram(a,b):
    for i in range(1, a+1):
        print('*' * (a+1-i) + '+' * b + '*' * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are printing with end='', which causes subsequent characters to be printed on the same line.  But at some point in your code, you need to add a print() to print on the next line.  Start there and see if you figure out where else it needs improvement.